# "Argument list too long" while executing cut and sed in a subshell to set a variable

Tags: bash, cut

I have written a bash script with has a python code embedded within it. What I did was read in the file and cut it with the below bash commands and then I exported it so that the python code could use it:

```
export BWA_compare=$(cut --output-delimiter='' -f1-3 ${BWA_AT}| sed 1d)
```

The problem is I get

```
/bin/cut: Argument list too long
/bin/sed: Argument list too long
```

It works on smaller files. Is there a limit on how much you can export?

Comment: The `sed` error doesn't make sense to me as the argument list contains just one element.

Comment: I have seen cases where in script the "Argument list too long" is raised against a line or command which is close to but which is not the problem. e.g. while loop read -r line which had echo $line |sed yadda; STRING+=stuff; "Argument list too long" was highlighted against the sed lines whereas the actual problem was STRING had grown too large. And STRING was not used in the sed lines.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is the error raised against sed and cut is a bit misleading. I think the error is that BWA_compare var is being assigned something that is too big.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863374/argument-list-too-long-error-when-i-run-any-command-in-linux-shell - one variable set in environment which was set too large caused all commands to fail. See in particular @chepner suggestion to read  https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Answer (score 2):

There are limits for both the number of arguments and the combined length of the arguments. These are not uniform values but depend of the system.

Usually such problems are solved with `xargs`.

But it seems to me that you are using `cut` wrongly. `cut` expects only files are arguments. Is `${BWA_AT}` a huge list of files? If it is the Python code then you need something like

```
echo "${BWA_AT}" | cut
```

If it really is a file list then you need something like

```
echo "${BWA_AT}" | xargs cut
```

with the needed `xargs` options depending on the separator.

Comment: The limit is on the cumulative size of the arguments and environment passed to `execve(2)`. There's also a limit on the size of single argument or env var string. For instance, after `export "a=$(yes | head -c129k)"`, you won't be able to run any command on current versions of Linux.

Comment: `${BWA_AT}` is just the file location. I was thinking that by exporting all the data that cut has generated I would run into a limit which produced those two errors.